# Is "worth to do" an acceptable alternative to "worth doing"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

It's also worth to mention the learning curve for both frameworks.

This is the sentence I came across.

Comment: Could you give a few examples/sentences where you would use this? I can't come up with any that aren't *worth **it** to do*.

Comment: To me “worth mentioning” or “worthwhile to mention” are the two idiomatic ways to say it.

Comment: You are on the wrong site. Try English Language Learners.

Answer (score 2):

In English, adjectival *worth* never occurs without a complement:

> Your house is worth *at least $250,000*.
>   Your house isn’t worth *renovating*.
>   Your house is worth *less than its appraised value*.
>   Even after the hurricane, your house must be worth *something*.
>   Your house isn’t worth *enough* to serve as collateral.
>   That play isn’t worth *the price of admission*.
>   That painting is a copy worth *practically nothing*.
>   It’s not worth *it* to drive all the way to Philadelphia.
>   She's worth *talking to*.

*Worth* following its complement means an amount:

> I could only buy *ten dollars worth*.

Acceptable constructions are nouns, noun phrases, pronouns, or gerund-participles. [An infinitive cannot be used](https://books.google.de/books?id=cxaQ9rvztGQC&pg=PA1685&dq=%22worth+to+do%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJr-PAn_PjAhVSkMMKHSLjDBEQ6AEIJjAA) without at least a dummy *it*, either as anticipatory subject or as complement:

> *It’s* not worth *it* to bet your career on such a risky venture.

In International English and certain Asian varieties, one does indeed find the construction you’re asking about. Quora.com, for instance, has hundreds of questions using an infinitive complement:

> Is it [*worth to do*](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-worth-to-do-scrum-master-certification-now-in-2019-in-India) scrum master certification now in 2019 in India?
>
> Is it [*worth to do*](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-worth-to-do-a-PhD-in-Universities-other-than-SKY-in-South-Korea) a PhD in Universities other than SKY in South Korea?
>
> Is it *[worth to do](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-worth-to-do-an-MTech-from-IIIT-Allahabad-in-information-technology-Do-they-get-placement-offers-as-much-as-the-B-Tech-students)* an MTech from IIIT-Allahabad in information technology? Do they get placement offers as much as the B.Tech students?

None of these questions would be considered standard English in the UK and Ireland, North America, Australia or New Zealand. Since the construction does appear in a headline in the *Times of India*, however, one could conclude that it is idiomatic for certain registers of Indian English:

> MBA Admission 2019: Why is MBA [*worth to do*](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/education/news/mba-admission-2019-why-is-mba-worth-to-do-bu/articleshow/67813811.cms)? — *Times of India*, 3 Feb. 2019.

Since one user has difficulty accessing the first link, here's a screenshot from *Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary*:

[image]

Comment: What is "International English"? In the US, it seems to mean "British English", but as you say, "worth to do" isn't standard in British English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I understand International English to be that variety spoken as a second language, especially beyond the Dutch and Scandinavians.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I can't bring myself to vote for it without some kind of objective evidence that it's *not* used in the US or UK. So far (again, although I agree), you're just stating your personal opinion that it's not. I know it's not possible to point to a negative—unless you can locate a grammar guide or something else. These sentences are fine: *I need to know its **worth to mention** it in my speech* and *I need to know its **worth to sell** it.* They use an infinitive, even though you've indicated that's not possible. So you at least need to be more specific about *worth*.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Read the first link.

Comment: You have several links. If you mean the one you titled "An infinitive cannot be used," it goes (for me) to a Google search result that returns the cover of the *Cambridge Advance Learner's Dictionary*. Plus, no matter what the think you'd intended it to show reads, it's still demonstrably wrong, given the two examples I provided that show an infinitive after *worth*. You need to much more carefully explain why the infinitive is possible in *that* use of the word.

Comment: @JasonBassford: You're using _worth_ as a noun. The prepositional phrase also isn't a complement. I really wanted to avoid the whole part of speech question: adjective, preposition, quasi-preposition. The link should have led you to a section explaining not to use a marked infinitive after [adj.] _worth_.

Comment: First, that needs to go into your answer. Because what you've actually *said* in the answer currently doesn't explain anything about how it's acceptable with nouns. Instead, it's a blanket statement that is actually incorrect in some situations. So, it's somewhat misleading. Second, the link sounds useful. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. [Here](https://imgur.com/XPwDOhR) is what I see when following the link.

Comment: Even if you can fix the link, you should still post the relevant portion of the text as a quotation in your answer. This is a good example of why link-only answers are discouraged.